# Not seeing the expected rainbow

Tags: visible-light

- I was expecting to see a rainbow inside the house from the sunlight coming through the window, at least when the sun is shining right through. Why wouldn't it?

But we just get the yellowish color of the white light after being "filtered" by the atmosphere.

- However if I put a CD-ROM then a rainbow appears in one of the walls. I understand this is diffraction but should this exact same phenomenon happen in the atmosphere as well, and we would see a rainbow in the atmosphere? As the particles could act as "diffractors". I am well aware about Rayleigh and Mie Scattering, but how do you make sense of these phenomenons ?

Comment: I've hidden a number of comments which should have been posted as answers to the question, and replies to them.

Answer (score 2):

*I was expecting to see a rainbow inside the house from the sunlight coming through the window, at least when the sun is shining right through. Why wouldn't it?*

You need to have your back to the Sun to see a rainbow.
If the sunlight is coming directly through the window, ie you can see the Sun, then you will not see a rainbow.

[image]

Note (look at the shadows) that you need to be between the light source and the water droplets and you will need to move your head and eyes around to get the angles right to observe a rainbow.

*I am well aware about Rayleigh [....] Scattering.*
Then you should understand that a rainbow is not the result of diffraction, rather the reflection and refraction of light from water droplets.
The CD has regularity in terms of the width and spacing of the tracks which act as a reflection grating whereas water droplets do not have such uniformity of order.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I did state that the cd acting like *a reflection [diffraction] grating*.

Comment: D'Oh! My mistake.

Comment: Missing my point respect to Rayleigh. I think the explanation is incomplete.

Comment: Why cant you see a rainbow with refraction only ? This is how it is done in every experment.

Comment: @MahNeh Which experiment?

Answer (score 1):

A first-order rainbow comes from light which has reflected from the backs of water droplets.  A "complete" rainbow forms a circle around the shadow of your head, with an apparent angular diameter of about 84º.  Usually the complete circle is only visible from the air.  If the sun is setting in the west, you would expect to see a rainbow centered around your shadow from a rainstorm to the east; the lower the sun, the closer you come to seeing a half-circle in the sky.

It is easy to make a rainbow from a garden hose on a sunny day.  If you have direct sunlight entering your house, you would not expect to see an indoor rainbow unless there are suspended water droplets in your house.  (Permit me to tell you a story about my children.)

There are higher-order rainbows produced by light which reflects more than once before exiting the water droplets.  The second-order rainbow is also in the shadow-ward direction; the space between the primary rainbow and the second-order rainbow is called [Alexander's dark band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_band).  There are third- and fourth-order rainbows which can appear in the sunward direction; [most people have never seen them](https://atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/ord34.htm).

Comment: Why not from refraction through a prism, that is, the water droplets?

Comment: Refraction by small droplets, without any internal reflection, doesn't occur in a coherent direction. Your prism has planar sides, but a raindrop does not. *Diffraction* in small droplets can cause [coronae](https://atoptics.co.uk/droplets/light2.htm). Refraction through ice crystals, which do have planar sides, can produce a number of different halos; the linked site has many excellent diagrams.